# Share post to facebook with title and content reactjs

Tags: reactjs, facebook, share

i'm using

```
<div ><a href={`https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${this.state.linkShare}`} target="_blank" ><FaFacebook /></a></div>
```

to share my post in react app to facebook, but it just display my ip like that:

[image]

I try to add meta tag but it doesn't word too :(

```
                <MetaTags>
                    <title>My Page 1</title>
                    <meta property="og:url" content={window.location.pathname} />
                    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
                    <meta name="description" content="description sd here.." />
                    <meta property="og:title" content="My App" />
                </MetaTags>
```

How  can i share my post with description to facebook with react js?

Answer (score 2):

OG Tags have to be in the original page source, you cannot set them dynamically with React. Facebook ignores JavaScript. One option is to use "Server Side Rendering", another one https://prerender.io/.

Comment: Do you give me another choose with react js?

Comment: i added a link to another solution

Comment: I have tried to put meta tag in index.html but it not working too. do i have to add some script to my app?

Comment: no - again, facebook does not parse javascript at all. please provide a test link and/or more details than just "it does not work". just make sure the og tags are in the original page source, without any javascript. and refresh the data in the debugger.